# How do I compare a hash value with an array value?

Tags: ruby, hash, cucumber

I'm passing to a function two arguments:

```
function_a(hash1, array1)
```

If I print the `class.name` of each argument inside the function (i.e `hash1.class.name`) it shows as:

```
Hash1:Hash & Array-1:Array
```

The members of both data structures before passing are:

Hash-1:

```
{:cmd=>"-add set isteautoSet1 2013-04-02 23:00:00",
 :criteria=>"isteautoSet1 2013-04-02 23:00:00",
 :setname=>"isteautoSet1",
 :operation=>"add"}
```

Array-1:

```
[{:setname=>"isteautoSet1",
  :numrules=>"0",
  :tests=>"0",
  :lastchanged=>"2013-03-30 06:35:40",
  :filtertype=>"summary",
  :expires=>"2013-04-02 23:00:00"},
 {:setname=>"set1",
  :filtertype=>["company"],
  :rulenum=>"1",
  :criteria=>"mydomain.com"},
 {:setname=>"set1",
  :filtertype=>["individual"],
  :rulenum=>"2",
  :criteria=>"yourdomain.com"}]
```

My goal in `function_a` is to:

Verify matching from the `array`-1 value of `("setname" + " " + "expires")` fields with the `hash-1` value `:criteria`.

I keep getting "can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError)" when I do the comparison. It looks like the issue is in accessing the array content using the "each" method.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right, maybe this is something for you:

```
rules.each do |hash|
    if hash.has_key?(:setname)
        if hash[:setname].eql?(cmd_hash[:setname])
             puts "found value"
        end
    end
end
```

This isn't the most clean way to do it but it offers a good base for starting.

Good luck! :)